# How To Change Background Resource of Button after Several Seconds

Tags: android, button, background, timer

I am creating an app which is like a memory game. A button has an image resource from a drawable and I want to the background resource of a button to go back to its default background, say after 5 seconds.

Here is my code.

```
 Collections.shuffle(ShapesArray);

   this.myImg1=ShapesArray.get(0);
   img1.setBackgroundResource(myImg1);

   task =  new TimerTask(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        img1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    }

   };

   Timer appear = new Timer();
   appear.schedule(task, 5000);

   img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            img1.setBackgroundResource(myImg1);
            String txt = PName.getText().toString();
             if(txt.equals("Heart")){
                    if(myImg1 == R.drawable.heart){
                        correct++;
                        img1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                    } 
                }
```

However, after the 5 Seconds, the Activity force closes and goes back to previous activity. I'm kinda new to Android. Please help. :(

Comment: Please post stack trace of force close.

Comment: here is the stack trace. http://shrib.com/stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either handler with post delay or can use count down timer ,here i am giving an example of count down and that is-

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
     }

     public void onFinish() {
    // After the time is experied so here can change image

      Printer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.prntr);       

     }
  }.start();
```

Thanks

Comment: what does 30000 and 1000 do? sorry newbie. :(

Comment: which will I change to 0? 30000 or 1000?

Comment: How much delay you want set it in place of 30000

Comment: Finally it worked! I'm still figuring different functions in Android so thank you for giving time to answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: Here 30000 is the total delay you want and another is after every 1000 millisecond expired it will go to tick()